# Illuminate\database query issue with select

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm trying to test various query structures and most work.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index($request, $response)
    {
        //return var_dump($container);
        //$user=$this->db->table('users')->find(1);
        //$user=$this->db->table('users')->where('id',1)->get();
        //$user=$this->db->table('users')->where('name','alex')->get();
        $user=$this->db->select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));
        var_dump($user);
        die();
        return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
    }
}
```

the queries slashed out are working but the last prior to var dump does not.

the error I am getting is this:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager::select()
```

this is config and caller page:

```
<?php
session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// $user = new \App\models\User;
// var_dump($user);
// die();

$app = new \Slim\app([
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'db' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'codecourse',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
         ]
    ],

]);

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

//set illuminate capsule
$capsule = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$container['db'] = function ($container) use ($capsule){
    return $capsule;
};


//Register Twig View helper
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
        'cache' => false/**'path/to/cache'**/,
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container->router,
        $container->request->getUri()
    ));

    return $view;
};


$container['HomeController'] = function($container){
    return new App\Controllers\HomeController($container);
};
```

disclaimer this is based on a tutorial I am following,
Slim is the very first framework I am learning and I am not sure how to even debug this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add and customize this container entry:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface as Container;

$container['db'] = function (Container $container) {
    $settings = $container->get('settings');
    $config = [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => $settings['db']['host'],
        'database' => $settings['db']['database'],
        'username' => $settings['db']['username'],
        'password' => $settings['db']['password'],
        'charset'  => $settings['db']['charset'],
        'collation' => $settings['db']['collation'],
        'prefix' => '',
    ];

    $factory = new ConnectionFactory(new \Illuminate\Container\Container());

    return $factory->make($config);
};
```

Then generate and execute a query. Use the `get()` method to fetch all rows:

```
$query = $this->db->table('users');
$query->select('id', 'username', 'email');
$query->where('id', '=', 1);

// fetch all rows (as stdClass)
$rows = $query->get();

// Alternative: fetch all rows as array
$rows = $query->get()->toArray();

var_dump($rows);
```

Raw Queries with PDO:

```
// Get the PDO object
$pdo = $this->db->getPdo();

// Use prepared statements
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= :id");
$statement->execute(['id' => 1]);
$userRow = $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your detailed reply,
Allow me to clarify,

I am trying to run something like:

`code $this->db->select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1)); `

This will allow me to use standard queries instead of the built in.

Can this be done?I'm sure its not the best practice but I still want to know.

Comment: The [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#select-raw) method could be used. Another way is to use the PDO object.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

Any controller add the following on top

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
```

then in function use like following sql

```
$alluseraddresses = Capsule::table('useraddresses')->where('user_id', '=', $_SESSION['userid'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use DB; //Top of your page

$user= DB::Select('users')->where('id','=',[$yourIds]);
```